# Align Social icons next to a menu

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xqt3mxpx/1

I need the social icons aligned to the right, and the menu to end before the social icons.

```
    #main-menu {
        float: right;
    }

    .social-icons {
        float: right;
        clear: right;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox on the `.container-fluid` element (I assigned it class `x1` in my fiddle, to which I assigned `display: flex`). And then put `margin-left: auto` on the `nav` element to move everything from there on to the right.

Plus I gave the header another background - black made everything invisible....

https://jsfiddle.net/u8vyxmfe/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use floats, you need to re-arrange the nav and social menu, so that both can be floated right and the social icons be on the far right. Then there is no need to `clear: right;` `.social-icons`, but to align it with the main nav, you need to apply the same vertical padding to `.social-icons` as you have on the nav menu links.

```css
#main-header {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#main-header .logo {
    float: left;
}
#main-menu {
    float: right;
}
#main-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#main-menu ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;  
}
#main-menu ul li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.social-icons {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px; 
}
.social-icons .fa {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header"> 
<div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="logo">
                <img src="logo" alt="Logo">
            </a>
  <div class="social-icons">
       
        <a style="display: inline-block" href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook "></i>F</a>
           
        <a href="http://googleplus.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>G+</a>
           
        <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>T</a>
    </div>    
 </div>
            
            <nav id="main-menu" class="menu-{menu slug}-container hidden-sm hidden-xs"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu clearfix"><li id="menu-item-15" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-15"><a href="http://localhost/avoar/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-18"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17"><a href="#">News</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-16"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></nav>            


</header>
```